# Hacer POST de una variable cuando se redirecciona usando HREF

Tags: php, javascript

Poseo una lista que genera un botón por cada registro existente, este recibe el `ID` del registro que le corresponde para luego hacer una redireccion a otra pagina si es pulsado.

Este es su **Codigo HTML:**

**Listado_Registros.html**

```
<input type="text" name="consultado" id="consultado">
<table>
<tr>
<th>ID del registro</th>
</tr>
<?php
while ($datos = $resultados->fetch_assoc())
{
?>
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT id FROM registros");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
?>
<tr>
<td><?php  $id = $datos['id'];  echo $id; ?></td>
<td><a onclick="enviame();" href="tablagrafica.php?id=<?=$id?>">Grafica</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

> SI hay error en el PHP, es porque trate de copiarlo lo mas reducido posible.
>
> El campo `consultado` se explicara mas adelante.

---

El archivo `tablagrafica.php` recibe ese `id` del comando `href` y muestra los datos perfectamente.

El problema esta en que:

- Si un usuario mete en el URL `tablagrafica.php?id=12412`, mostrara esa grafica y quisiera evitar eso.

---

Por lo que aplique la siguiente solución:

*Colocare un campo oculto y que el valor de este campo sea comparado al tratar de acceder a la tabla grafica, si no es el valor esperado no podra mostrarla.*

Esto lo hice con este código JS llamado `enviame()`:

```
function enviame(){
   var agree=confirm("\u00BFDesea obtener esta grafica?.");
   if (agree){
   document.getElementById("consultado").value = 1;
   return true ;
   }
   else
   return false ;   
   }
```

Su funcion era colocar un valor en el campo de texto llamado `consultado` y cuando se redireccionara al archivo `tablagrafica.php` este lo `POSTEARA` si existía el valor la mostraba sino **NO**, comparandolo con 1.

**tablagrafica.php:**

```
$consultado = $_POST["consultado"];
if ($consultado== 1)
  {
  //Conexion y grafica.
  $id=$_REQUEST["id"]; //Esto funciona bien.
  }
  else
  {
  echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");
  }
```

*Que ocurrió:* **No funciono.**

> Creo que actúa antes el `HREF` que el código JS, porque siempre me
>   dice que no esta definido la variable de `consultado`.

*Leyendo consegui que para que obtuviera el valor de `consultado` debia hacer un `submit`.
Si lo hago mediante el javascript `formulario.submit`, este no conseguirá el valor del `ID`, ya que dicho valor se genera para cada botón y al usar `REQUEST` esperara un valor por `HEADER`.
Si trato de obtener con `POST` el `ID` no funciona, solo me consigue el ultimo `ID` que se mostró con el `HTML`, si hay 30 registros y pulso el boton del primero, me obtendrá el `id = 30`*

**Concluyo:** Quisiera que al redireccionar mediante el `HREF` se obtuiera el `ID` del registro y tambien se hiciera el `POST` de la variable `consultado` para así tener mayor seguridad al obtener la tabla gráfica.

Modificacion sugerida por @Lixus:

**Listado.html**

```
<input type="text" name="consultado" id="consultado">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>ID del registro</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while ($datos = $resultados->fetch_assoc())
    {
    ?>
    $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT id FROM registros");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    ?>
    <tr>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php  $id= $datos['id'];  echo 
    $id; ?>" hidden>
    <td><?php  $id = $datos['id'];  echo $id; ?></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="ver" id="ver" value="Ver"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

**Que ocurrio:** Al hacer click en cualquiera de los `POST` toma el ultimo `ID` que existe

Modificacion sugerida por @Robertos:

**Listado.html**

```
    <form name="listado" id="listado" method="POST">
            <table>
            <tr>
            <th>ID del registro</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while ($datos = $resultados->fetch_assoc())
            {
            ?>
            $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT id FROM registros");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($id);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();
            ?>
            <tr>

            <input type="text" name="id" value="" hidden>

            <td><?php  $id = $datos['id'];  echo $id; ?></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:enviame('tablagrafica.php', '<?=$id?>')">Ver</a></td>
            <?php
            }

                ?>
<input type="text" id="consultado" value="1";
```

Javascript

```
function enviame(laUrl, elId){
  var elform =document.getElementById("listado");
  var eldato=document.getElementById("id");
  eldato.value=elId;
  elform.action=laUrl;
  elform.submit();
}
```

**tablagrafica.php**

**Que ocurrio:** al pulsar el boton de ver hace la redireccion pero `tablagrafica.php` me dice que consultando y `id` no estan definidos

Al hacer alert de elform y el dato, devuelven undefined y el id.

**tablagrafica.php**

```
  $consultado = $_POST["consultado"];
  $id = $_POST["id"];
  if ($consultado== 1)
  {
  //Conexion y grafica.
  $id=$_REQUEST["id"]; //Esto funciona bien.
  }
  else
  {
  echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");
  }
```

Comment: Has una forma normal, y en tu action pon tu variable GET, así puedes combinar tanto POST como GET en una misma forma `action='tablagrafica.php?id=<?=$id?>'`

Comment: @Lixus donde pondria esa action? en el action del listado?

Comment: `<form action='tablagrafica.php?id="<?=$id?>"'> </form>`

Comment: ¿qué necesidad hay de usar `consultado`? Si confirma el dialogo, haz un `location.href = "http://..."`

Comment: Aunque yo recomendaría mejor usar puro post, y crea un input donde su value le pongas el id mediante php, así no sufrirías por ese tipo de problemas que comentas en tu post. `<input type='text' value='"<?$id?>"' style='display:none'/>`

Comment: @cnbandicoot lo uso para evitar que metan en URL una ruta forzada, ya que si una persona mete en el header id=659 mostrara ese dato, quiero forzar al usuario a que deba pulsar el boton, si el boton se pulsa este lo manda para alla, junto a un valor que es comparado. si consultado es 1, en la tabla se hara post de ese consultado.

Comment: @Victor-Random Para evitar eso, manda el id por POST y no por GET

Comment: @cnbandicoot y como lo mando si se generan mucchos registros y al hacer post como dije en la pregunta me jala el ultimo solamente.? publciare mas codigo del listado

Comment: @Lixus te refieres a crear un input con el ID por cada registro como hice con el boton javascript? y luego?

Comment: Mira viendo el código de PHP que agregaste, y sin alejarte de tu lógica, pienso que lo ideal sea que en el while, crees una forma por cada registro que consultas. que contenga un input escondido, donde almacenes el valor de tu id y un botón donde al dar submit puedas recuperar mediante POST y no GET en tu página de tablagrafica el valor que enviaste mediante el input escondido.

Comment: Así te evitas el usar el confirm y cualquier otro código de javascript y tu URL se protegerá de que alguien meta mano a tu variable GET ya que no la ocuparías más.

Comment: @Lixus probare eso

Comment: @Lixus publicare los cambios en la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
<html>
   <!-- Todos lo que necesites de css, js.... -->

   <script>
   function enviame(laUrl, elId){
      var elform =document.getElementById("MiForm");
      var eldato=document.getElementById("id");
      eldato.value=elId;
      elform.action=laUrl;
      elform.submit();
   }
   </script>
<body>
   <!-- en algun lugar un form -->
   <form id="MiForm" name="MiForm" method="post" >
     <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="" />
     <input type="hidden" id="consultado" name="consultado" value="1" />
   </form>

<!-- cambia lo que armas a -->
<?php
   // Como tengas tu codigo
?>
<tr>
<td><?php  $omd = $datos['id'];  echo $id; ?></td>
<td><a href="javascript:enviame('tablagrafica.php', '<?=$id?>')">Grafica</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
// Como tengas tu código
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Notas:
@Victor-Random mira de nuevo, agregue *consultado* puse igual ID que NAME del FORM y el INPUT le agregue VALUE como vacio.

Comment: Ya funciona, tenia mal unas lienas, ya pasa a la tabla grafica pero me dice que no esta definido el id, como lo recupero? por post? get? request?

Comment: @Victor-Random omitiste parte al publicar lo que puse; te sugiero revises; asi mismo si los parámetros los quieres recibir por post o get solo en *method" del form cambialo según necesites. En caso que te de error no olviden mencionar el error especifico así como la línea donde lo marca.

Comment: Correcto me faltaba una parte jejeje, funciono perfecto